# What is the meaning of this Android SDK icon?

Tags: android, sdk

What is the meaning of this Android SDK icon?

[image: folder with white triangle]

I even open the manual only to see 100's beautiful icons and their descriptions except for this one.

[EDIT] I am specifically asking about the white triangle seen on many folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the meaning of this Android SDK icon?

This icon is not from the Android SDK. It is from Eclipse, with the Android Developer Tools plugin.

> I specifically asking about the white triangle seen on many folders

I believe that is the letter "a", and AFAIK it signifies a folder that is managed by the Android Developer Tools plugin (versus other folders managed more natively by Eclipse, or ones ignored by the build tools entirely).

Answer (score 0):

There you can put .jar files and will be aded to the build path. So if you need to use an external lib, you put it there.